# Extending Devise to use login with phone number and OTP as well as normal email and password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a rails app which has devise implemented on the model **USER**.Normal login using email and password works fine.I have also implemented two factor authentication which works perfectly.
Now,i want to login the user with phone number and OTP while keeping my current authentication implementation intact also.So,basically a user can either login using email and password OR using his phone number and OTP.
I have gone through the articles explaining how to override the default authentication attributes but i want to extend them so i can have users login using 2 different ways.

I am stuck on how to create the user session using phone number and OTP.I have done the part of verifying the OTP,just left with creating a user session.

Comment: When you say that you already implemented 2fa, what do you mean exactly? because what you are trying to achieve sounds like an implementation of 2fa authentication...

Comment: What i mean is that i already have implemented complete flow of 2FA but i want to implement another authentication method which authenticates user just by phone and OTP!

Comment: By 'phone' you mean they will provide a phone number that you will store in your database as identifier?

Comment: Yes! Anyways i was able to do this myself!

Comment: Can you share how you implememnted this ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have access to that codebase now.